# alert jquery slider problems with ui.value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

when i move the first slider and pressed second button it is showing value of first slider and vice versa , but i want the value of second slider only

html

```
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>
<div class="slider"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
<input type="button" class="ab" value="send">
<div class="slider"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
<input type="button" class="ab" value="send">
```

jquery

```
$(".slider").slider(
{
        value:1,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            a=ui.value;
            $(ui.handle).closest(".slider").next( "p").find(".slider-value").html( ui.value );
        }
}
);

$( ".slider-value").html(  $('.slider').slider('value') );

$(".ab").click(function(){
alert(a);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1937/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get value from second slider on button click

**HTML**

```
 <h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>
<div>
<div class="slider"></div>

<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
<input type="button" class="ab" value="send" />
 </div>


<div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
<input type="button" class="ab" value="send" />
 </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(".ab").click(function(){
  a=  $(this).closest('div').find('.slider').slider("option", "value");
  alert(a);
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1958/)**

Comment: but moving second slider and pressing first button gives the value of second slider

Comment: it works in jsfiddle but when i used it in my program it shows[ object object]

Comment: @user1673591 May be something wrong in your programm,have you wrap with the div?

Comment: @user1673591 I added an extra div for each block,Please check html also,it will work

Comment: still same object object...wat the above statement says a=  $(this).closest('div').find('.slider').slider("option", "value");

Comment: @user1673591 Both html are the same?

Comment: pls explain me the statement so it helps me further pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60674/discussion-between-shin-and-user1673591).

Answer (score 0):

You have to have diff handle on diff sliders. I have made it with diff `Ids`

Check my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/khaleel/hxe0wg6w/1/

Hope it helps

Comment: yours is what i excepted so i can't do it with classes?

Comment: you cant achive it with single button class, Since it always overides the old value, Best approach is to have diff Ids . Please vote up and accept my answer since it works for you

Comment: using class names as selector are recommended only for CSS purposes. So use IDs, that is best approach for selectors

Comment: I think,class name not only for css.

Comment: This example includes usage of global variable

Comment: @Shin I didn't said class name **only** for CSS, please read comments carefully

Comment: @Wexoni is there any issue using global variables in this, to achieve what we want here.

Comment: No issues, it works like my example which does not use globals. Common practice is to avoid using global variables.

Comment: I still wonder what is the roadblock in accepting my answer, Which is working as expected

Answer (score -1):

This is one way of doing what you need. Please check this Fiddle to see JS code as well, so I dont spam this place with js code.

```
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>

<div id="sliderone" class="slider"></div>

<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
<input id="buttonone" type="button" class="ab" value="send">

<div id="slidertwo" class="slider"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
<input id="buttontwo" type="button" class="ab" value="send">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/25ccz9g3/

Comment: In this example first button gives value of first slider. Second button gives value of second slider. What is it exactly that you need?

Comment: on moving slider corresponding values should be alerted